# Make a div scrollable (when it has ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scroll, overflow

This is the html code I have:

```
 <div id="header_context" class="scroll">
    <div id="column_scroll" class="column" ng-repeat="column in columns track by column.name" ng-hide="column.name == 'date'" ng-click="column.visible = !column.visible">
        <div class="checkmark" ng-class="{'checked': column.visible}"></div>
        <div class="" ng-bind-html="column.title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This I have in my css:

```
#column_scroll{
  overflow: scroll;
}
.scroll{
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

This is a function that I have inside the .js:

```
  $('#timeline_container #content .trips_header').on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    hideContextMenu();
    $('#header_context').css({
        display: 'block',
        left: e.clientX,
        top: e.clientY,
        overflow:scroll
    });
    $('#header_context > div').click(function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

This is what my inspector sees:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/lPNa4qbS34P6dVE/upload.png

PS: I tried changing from the inspector overflow - scroll, but still, it is blocked. Do I need to add something else?

PPS: This is how it looks on a PC or if the inspector is closed:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/b37eCtrQIfgV4dt/upload.png
This is how it looks with the inspector on, or laptop:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/qSquGYY8ZWulHZm/upload.png

As you can see, The list doesn't fit, and it is not scrollable.

Comment: If there is nothing to scroll `overflow: scroll` will just make the scrollbars visible (they will be inactive). `overflow: auto` will show the scrollbars when necessary (when there is something to scroll). -- btw, there is no class `scroll` or id `column_scroll` in the html.

Comment: modified the code. sorry. I was playing with git-reset and that happened.
Well, it should be scrollable. I have a list of items that are checkable. BUT if it's a laptop, not all the list is visible, and I cannot scroll down to select another object from the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing some html code.
By the way, if you want it to be scrollable, div "header_context" or any div that is going to contain the ng-repeat items has to have a height or max-height attribute defined, and then make it "overflow-y:scroll;" so if children ng-repeat divs height surpases parent height, parent becomes scrollable.

Comment: Just another quick question:
this works:
`var header = document.getElementById('header_context')
  header.style.maxHeight = '150px';`

But this doesn't:
`header.style.maxHeight = (document.body.offsetHeight - e.clientY);`
What am I missing? how can I declare my value as "px"

Comment: Try header.style.maxHeight = (document.body.offsetHeight - e.clientY)+'px';

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I'm an android developer, so still a bit noob-ish with javascript

Comment: You are wellcome! =)